# Interface Orientation won't change to Landscape on App Launch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad, orientation

i stuck on a problem that drives me crazy!
I have an iPad application starting with a TabBarViewController. Every Tab has it's own ViewController and nib-file.

To make interface orientation possible I added all orientations to my info.plist and subclassing my TabBarController to set:

```
        - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return YES;
}
```

Every View is autoresized and formatted well for displaying the right Orientation if I rotate the Interface. If I test it in the simulator, everything looks fine and I can rotate between the Orientations.

Now the point that drives me crazy:

If I launch the App in Portrait Mode, all works fine.. but if I launch in Landscape, I get an error and my Interface orientation seems still to be Portrait, while the Simulator is in Landscape Mode!!

The Error:

```
2011-05-24 21:50:15.011 Project[57995:207] Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations.
```

I checked for Orientation like this:

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];



    if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
        NSLog(@"Orientation: Landscape");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Orientation: Portrait");
    }

}
```

The Log says it is in "Landscape" Mode if I launch in Landscape, but if I change tab to another it looks terrible because the View is displayed in Portrait mode instead.
On change back to the start-view where i asked for Orientation… the log displays "Portrait"… but the Simulator is still Landscape!

I can't figure out why the Orientation is Portrait on start,…
even if I start in Landscape…

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the `info.plist` setting for `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`?

Comment: I added all items for Supported Interface Orientations in info.plist.. the first one is Portrait (bottom home button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

Simply used this in viewWillAppear method of all my Views, to make it work when started in Landscape mode:

```
if(([[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)){        
    //Landscape View
}
else{
    //Portrait View
}
```

Works fine for me!

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So the documentation says `viewWillAppear:` is called prior to all animations. And when your app starts, its initial orientation is `Portrait`. Based on what your orientation is, it then rotates to that orientation. Since it animates to the orientation off screen, this must be called after `viewWillAppear:`/ So when `viewWillAppear:` is called, its still in `Portrait`. I tested this myself.