# iOS Orientation: Tried this and tried that

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

The app will show stuff on a second display fine.  Issue is when I when I rotate the iPad the content doesn't rotate on the iPad.

Have looked at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html
[Interface Orientation won't change to Landscape on App Launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116248/interface-orientation-wont-change-to-landscape-on-app-launch)
[iPhone SDK: Orientation (Landscape and Portrait views)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431165/iphone-sdk-orientation-landscape-and-portrait-views)
http://www.bytesizecreations.com/2009/05/working-with-orientation-changes-on/
[iPhone app in landscape mode, 2008 systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode)
[iPhone app in landscape mode, 2008 systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode)
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7366-interface-builder-landscape-design.html#post186977

Anyone who could tell me exactly what I need to add would be appreciated! :)

```
#import "iPadVGAOutputTestAppDelegate.h"

@implementation iPadVGAOutputTestAppDelegate

@synthesize deviceWindow;
@synthesize consoleTextView;
@synthesize externalWindow;

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    externalWindow.hidden = YES;


    // Make iPad window visible.
    [deviceWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Check for external screen.
    if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1) {
        [self log:@"Found an external screen."];

        // Internal display is 0, external is 1.
        externalScreen = [[[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1] retain];
        [self log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"External screen: %@", externalScreen]];

        screenModes = [externalScreen.availableModes retain];
        [self log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Available modes: %@", screenModes]];

        // Allow user to choose from available screen-modes (pixel-sizes).
        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"External Display Size" 
                                                         message:@"Choose a size for the external display." 
                                                        delegate:self 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
        for (UIScreenMode *mode in screenModes) {
            CGSize modeScreenSize = mode.size;
            [alert addButtonWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f x %.0f pixels", modeScreenSize.width, modeScreenSize.height]];
        }
        [alert show];

    } else {
        [self log:@"External screen not found."];
    }

    return YES;
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIScreenMode *desiredMode = [screenModes objectAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    [self log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Setting mode: %@", desiredMode]];
    externalScreen.currentMode = desiredMode;

    [self log:@"Assigning externalWindow to externalScreen."];
    externalWindow.screen = externalScreen;

    [screenModes release];
    [externalScreen release];

    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
    rect.size = desiredMode.size;
    externalWindow.frame = rect;
    externalWindow.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [self log:@"Displaying externalWindow on externalScreen."];
    externalWindow.hidden = NO;
    [externalWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)log:(NSString *)msg
{
    [consoleTextView setText:[consoleTextView.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\r", msg]]];
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [consoleTextView release];
    [deviceWindow release];
    [externalWindow release];

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 3):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is a `UIViewController` method. The application delegate doesn't make use of that method. You should create a `UIViewController` subclass and put your content on its view. You will have to set appropriate `autoresizingMasks` on the view or relay your views on every rotation.

But if you intend to persist on using the application delegate, you should use the `UIDevice` singleton to generate notifications on orientation changes which you can listen to.